# how to get subscript into formulas text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in excel I need to get this to be a subscript in the output.

Basically I want all the numbers in the output to be subscripted

I have tried this code, and it is part of a large IF "loop"

```
B2=2

=(B2="","","C"&B2) = C2
```

where I desire an output like this C_2
(any help to get an actual C subscript her in the question box and not C_2, when making the question, would also be helpful)

the formatting did not work because this is a generic and changing out put where these change with other elements giving different output like

C2O2H, C6H6, C4ON ,C4H6N4 C5H8S2 Etc.

and you can only manually format output once done making the combination, then the next time you need to start over, instead of formatting I need a formula that does this for me, or VBA.

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Convert Digits To Subscript (H₂SO₄)

**Excel Formula Improvement (Edit)**

- A huge improvement was suggested by David Leal in the comments:

```
=LET(d,A1,
    ds,MID(d,SEQUENCE(LEN(d)),1),
TEXTJOIN("",,IFERROR(UNICHAR(832&ds),ds)))
```

- The `LAMBDA` function would be something like this:

```
=LAMBDA(Compound,
    LET(ds,MID(Compound,SEQUENCE(LEN(Compound)),1),
TEXTJOIN("",,IFERROR(UNICHAR(832&ds),ds))))
```

See in the continuation how to use it.

**Excel Formula (Function)**

```
=LET(d,A1,
    ds,MID(d,SEQUENCE(LEN(d)),1),
    s,MOD(SEQUENCE(10),10),
TEXTJOIN("",,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(--ds,s,0)),UNICHAR(832&ds),ds)))
```

- You could create a `LAMBDA` function:

```
=LAMBDA(Compound,LET(
    ds,MID(Compound,SEQUENCE(LEN(Compound)),1),
    s,MOD(SEQUENCE(10),10),
TEXTJOIN("",,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(--ds,s,0)),UNICHAR(832&ds),ds))))
```

- Using `Ribbon->Formulas->Defined Names->Define Name`, you need to come up with a name (e.g. `Chem`, `Compound`, `SubComp`...) and enter it into the `Name:` box and enter the formula into the `Refers to:` box. Now you can use the function e.g. simply with

  ```
  =Chem(A1)
  =Chem("H2SO4")
  ```
- Note that you can use the function in the entire workbook.

**VBA**

```vb
Function Chemis(ByVal Compound As String) As String
    
    Dim n As Long, Char As String, Comp As String
    
    For n = 1 To Len(Compound)
        Char = Mid(Compound, n, 1)
        If Char Like "#" Then
            Comp = Comp & ChrW(832 & Char)
        Else
            Comp = Comp & Char
        End If
    Next n
    
    Chemis = Comp

End Function
```

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of this UNICHAR trick to create subscripts, maybe I am missing something, but what about this?`=LET(d,A1,ds,MID(d,SEQUENCE(LEN(d)),1),TEXTJOIN("",,IFERROR(UNICHAR(832&ds),ds)))`

Comment: @DavidLeal Great. If that's not an improvement then what is: it's 55 characters shorter and when copied to 1M rows, Excel recovers after 22s, while my solution takes 25s. I don't know, but I think you should post it because just crediting you in my answer doesn't feel right (enough). I don't mind, surely you can do something like *"Building on the idea... I came up with...improvement...*". Obviously, I have a lack of knowledge of all the tricks and ideas before 365. I'm a VBA guy, right?

Comment: Thanks, but it is fine, I could not come to your idea alone, I wasn't feeling good posting a new answer, when it is the same idea, just an improvement over yours, but thanks anyway. If you like, you can update your answer and give me credit, that is good enough

Comment: Then I'll incorporate it since it mustn't go to waste in the comments.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Damn this is satisfying to pullout of the toolbox, other than using it in a formula, i often import tables from book, via Text -> CSV, loosing the subscripts and manually setting via formatting and now i just run this for a range and i am done, so i am great full for the multiple solutions (for anybody who wants to know the VBA is god for ranges so is Ribbon)